# Ionic app startup time

Tags: ionic2

Just getting into this ionic framework. build an simple app with just a tab and menu, deploy to android phone. it seems like it takes a good 3 seconds to load. the black screen last for 3 seconds then the app shows. I also try the ionicview app from ionic. similar experience. my question is, is it just something I missed or it's just one of the draw back of this kind of hybrid app? it make sense that the webview need to load and parse the js and html then render the UI.

Answer (score 0):

Crosswalk provides a bundled Chrome Webview with the app, resulting in better performance and predictability.  It helps a lot on older Androids and also speeds up the newer phones.

Comment: Yea but a larger package to download.

Comment: True, but I am finding when Apps get more complex I am finding it a life saver